# Remove/filter data by another query result

Tags: sql, postgresql

*LIST-OF-DAYS* = `SELECT day FROM TABLE1`

#### Sample data from TABLE 1

```
         day
---------------------
 2014-01-20 00:00:00
 2014-01-21 00:00:00
 2014-01-22 00:00:00
```

I want to remove/filter data by the above result *LIST-OF-DAYS*.
How do I apply the filter on `SELECT datetime, value FROM TABLE2`?

#### Sample data from TABLE 2

```
       datetime        | volume
-----------------------+--------
 2014-01-02 01:14:00.5 |    364
 2014-01-20 01:15:01.5 |    149
 2014-01-22 01:15:01.5 |    149
```

#### Pseudo code

`SELECT * FROM TABLE2 WHERE (TABLE2.datetime in LIST_OF_DAYS)`

By the way, there is a column `TABLE2.datetime`. Therefore,

- It should be *reserved* if `datetime = '2014-01-20 19:13:00'`
- It should be *removed* if `datetime = '2014-03-20 09:10:20'`

#### Desired result

```
       datetime        | volume
-----------------------+--------
 2014-01-20 01:15:01.5 |    149
 2014-01-22 01:15:01.5 |    149
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE2 where day in (SELECT day FROM TABLE1);
```

This is just of an example of how you could use result of a query in another query. The where clause will select only those rows from **TABLE2** which have **'day'** column value matching with **TABLE1 'day'** column value.

Answer (score 0):

You want to rows from `table2`, where the value in column `day` exists in `table1.day`. Use an [`[INNER] JOIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html) for this.
There is some additional complication with data types. The way you have it, with data type [**`timestamp`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html):

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM   table1 t1
JOIN   table2 t2 ON t2.datetime >= t1.day
                AND t2.datetime <  t1.day + interval '1 day';
```

Simpler if you use [**`date`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) for `table1.day` (and still timestamp for `t2.datetime`):

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM   table1 t1
JOIN   table2 t2 ON t2.datetime >= t1.day
                AND t2.datetime <  t1.day + 1;  -- just add int to date
```

There is a shorter form, too:

```
JOIN   table2 t2 ON t2.datetime::date = t1.day::date
```

But the long version above is [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) and can use an **index** on `table2.datetime`.